# Forcing a dll to be loaded from a specific folder instead of /BIN

Tags: asp.net, dll, dllimport

I have two versions of the same dll (with the same strong name), one residing in the default BIN folder, one in a different folder (e.g. DifferentDllFolder), which is not a subdirectory of the app root. How can I specify a web.config setting to force asp.net to load the dll from the DifferentDllFolder instead of the BIN folder? Is there a way to override the lookup order?

I've tried setting the CodeBase, as well as Add Assembly, but asp.net always chooses the dll from the BIN folder. If I delete the dll in the BIN folder, the dll from the DifferentDllFolder gets loaded, but I can't delete the BIN folder version.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be much, much easier to just make sure that your code can use the same dll version... But if that library is open source i guess you could refactor one so it has a different name.

Comment: Not sure how _asp.net_ loads *.dll*s (whether they are simple or assemblies), but [\[MSDN\]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) might help.